# Lomdus Seforim Organized Along Sugyot

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books

What are essential seforim (by masechet) that are organized by sugya; preferably ones that give a basic overview of the lomdus involved.

Comment: Can any book of summaries really be characterized as "essential"?

Comment: With this kind of thing it is more personal preference than anything. You would do better with a good shiur that you like.

Comment: the mesivta is very good on that free on the otsar

Comment: ספר כסף נבחר awesome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some excellent *lomdus* sefarim *al seder mesechta*:

- Birchas Avraham, by R' Avrohom Erlanger. Contemporary Brisker approach, both diyukkim and lomdus. Written *al hadaf*, but with an introduction to most sugyas. Mostly available on Hebrewbooks.org
- Moreshes Moshe, by R' Moshe Steinhaus. Rishonim based summaries on the different *mehalchim* on each sugya. Fantastic *mareh mekomos* and comprehensive analysis of most sugyos. Some available on Hebrewbooks.org, all available on Otzar Hachochma.
- Kehillas Yaakov, by the Steipler Gaon.
- Gevuras Yitzchok, available on Hebrewbooks.org
- Kuntras Habiurim, by R' Moshe Shmuel Shapira. Revolutionary lomdus, not an easy read.

Comment: Are any of these organized by sugya?

Comment: All of them are, except *Birchas Avraham* which is organized by *daf*, but periodically - generally at the beginning of each new *sugya* - has a piece titled 'בענין...' where he discusses the sugya. *Kuntras Habiurim* is mainly organized by sugya, but at the end he has short *ha'aros al hadaf* organized by *daf*.

Answer (score 0):

Kehillas Yaakov by the Steipler, Rav Yaakov Yisrael Kanievsky zt"l. I find that the more work I put into studying a topic, the more depth I find in his analysis of the sugya.

Comment: Where can one find Kehillas Yaakov?

Comment: Try a seforim store.